# Cannot connect docker image to kafka container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, spring-kafka

I am trying to connect my Kafka container and my docker image all running locally
and don't want to create a container with Kafka and zookeeper images.

When I am running the app without dockerizing it, it is working fine.

After running the dockerize app the docker logs is showing

```
could not read message dial tcp 172.21.0.3:9092: i/o timeout
```

in Kafka logs, it is showing

```
kafka-zookeeper-1  | 2021-12-07 06:17:15,755 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-7:ZooKeeperServer@1411] - Connection request from old client /172.18.0.1:56350; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
```

this is the docker compose for kafka

```
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - /Users/myuser/docker/volumes/kafka:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

Can anyone help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if i understand correctly then you are running kafka on  ur local machine and want to connect it from docker app. see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: One log line isn't enough information to help. You need to show your apps bootstrap connection and your docker run commands / compose files